# Управление наполением страницы со своей html структурой [opencart 2]

Tags: opencart, i18n

**Подскажите как правильно сделать**: у меня есть страница с кастомной структурой. Это страница на которой выводятся данные (мультиязычные) по проекту в виде табов (в которых текст с картинками), для этого был создан отдельный котролер который отдает блок с контентом + есть еще отдельная страница на которой выводиться галлерея проекта, и тоже было бы неплохо редактировать ее через админку.

Cейчас данные на страницу подтягиваются с "языковых файлов", но проблемма в том что редактировать и править эти самые данные будет менеджер, а в php файлы он лезть точно не будет, нужно дать возможность править через админку.

Стандартный редактов в админке opencart режить все теги или как минимум произвольные стилевые классы. Можно ли как-то в админке редактировать переменные стилевых фалов (навряд ли), или есть какое-то решение + у меня много разных текстовых (информационных) блоков (с произвольной html структурой) по страницах разбросано, было бы не плохо чтобы их можно было редактировать через админку а не через файлы (мультиязычность обязательная).

Answer (score 0):

Я работаю с опенкарт2 и, судя по вашему вопросу, кажется что либо вы выбрали не ту кмс, либо не совсем понимаете суть локализации проекта.

Файлы локализации отвечают за перевод темы. Не больше и не меньше. Весь стандартный набор диалогов, текстов кнопок, статичного контента - весь задаётся там. Т.е. та локализация, которая со временем не претерпивает больших изменений.

Нам часто заходят на рефакторинг проекты на OC2, в которых люди умудряются запихнуть в файлы локализации целые куски шаблона с html-разметкой. Это вредительство в прямом смысле.

Если вам нужна возможность править блоки с информацией, вы должны использовать модули из стандартного функционального набора данной системы. Например, модуль "HTML Содержимое", который позволяет создавать вам блоки основанные на html-разметке. И далее управлять выводом экземпляром модуля в тех местах шаблона, где это необходимо. Помимо того есть множества сторонних модулей из разряда "Не учи админку, а поставь вот это!"

Стандартный функционал OC2 позволяет вам гибко управлять контентом, его выводом, распределением и локализацией. Ознакамливайтесь с документацией и не рубите паттерн, на котором сидите)))